# Unexpected result from apollo react's useQuery method

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-context

For a project, where i've implemented authentication by running a GraphQL query inside a  `AuthenticationProvider` from a context, I noticed the query is fetching data twice.

```
const AuthenticationProvider: FC = props => {  
  const {
    loading,
    data 
  } = useQuery(MeQuery)
    
  if (loading) return null
    
  return <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={{user: data?.me || null}} {...props} />
}
```

However the query runs perfect, I still wanted to know why it fetches the data twice. I did some googling, and came across this issue, where [this answer](https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/issues/157#issuecomment-491151909) was provided. I tried the same thing, with the `skip` option, based if the data is loaded.

```
const [skip, setSkip] = useState(false)

const {
  loading,
  data 
} = useQuery(MeQuery, { skip })

useEffect(() => {
  if (!loading && data?.me) {
     setSkip(true)
  }
}, [loading, data])

// ...
```

But when logging in, it stopped working.

```
const useLoginMutation = () => useMutation(LOGIN_QUERY, { update: (cache, { data }) => {
  if (!data) {
    return null
  }

  cache.writeQuery({ query: MeQuery, data: { me: data.login } }) 
}
})
```

The cache still get's updated with the right values, but doesn't retrieve the user anymore (null).

```
const { user } = useContext(AuthenticationContext)
```

What am I missing here? It seems the query did run and fetched the correct data.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use context when you are using apollo useQuery. If you make a query first, then the data fetched will be stored in the cache. You can directly access the data from the cache for the second you run the query. Since useQuery has default `fetchPolicy` [`cache-first`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#caching-query-results). Mean its check in the cache first, if no query made before it makes a network request.

If you want to avoid network loading. You can make a top-level component `AuthWrapper`.

```js
const useUserQuery = () => useQuery(ME_QUERY);

const AuthWrapper = ({children}) => {
  const {loading, data} = useUserQuery();
  
  if(loading) return null
  
  return children;
}



export GetUsetInThisComponent = ({}) => {
  // Since we have fetched the user in AuthWrapper, the user will be fetched from the cache.
  const {data} = useUserQuery();
  
  // No you can access user from data?.user
  
  // Rest of the application logic
  
  
}

// Wrap the component like this to avoid loading in the children components

<AuthWrapper>
  <GetUserInThisComponent />
</AuthWrapper>
```

Comment: Ís the reason for querying more then once the context?